# Magento2 translation issue after js/css merge

Tags: magento2

I am facing an issue in magento2 translation after js css merge.

```
ko i18n: 'Méthode'
```

becomes MÃ©thode.it should display Méthode instead MÃ©thode.
Without js/css merge it is working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have faced similar issue below solutions were used.

1. Move the translation to translation CSV for Js created contents
2. use unicodes in place of special characters eg é as (& eacute; without space between & an e) [ better to use this solution only when the content is in HTML)